# The derived $\infty$-category of sheaves on a site is closed symmetric monoidal

Tags: homological-algebra, higher-category-theory, model-categories, derived-categories, higher-algebra

Let $X$ be a quasicompact semiseparated scheme. I am trying to recover the (closed) symmetric monoidal structure on $\mathcal{D}(\mathrm{QCoh}(X))$, the derived $\infty$-category of quasicoherent sheaves on $X$. As such I would like to use the flat model structure on $\mathrm{Ch}(\mathrm{QCoh}(X))$ from Gillespie's *Kaplansky classes and derived categories* and conclude with Lurie, *Higher algebra*, 4.1.7.6 and 4.1.7.10., which say that the underlying $\infty$-category of a *simplicial* symmetric monoidal model category is symmetric monoidal. But, as far as I understand $\mathrm{Ch}(\mathrm{QCoh}(X))$ is not simplicial. Is there a way to recover the result ? I would be more interested in references which I could cite.

In the case of $X=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ with $R$ a commutative ring, there might be a workaround going as : $\mathcal{D}(R)$ identifies with the $\infty$-category of $HR$-module spectra so is symmetric monoidal because the $\infty$-category of spectra is ; but I must admit that this sort of argument is too advanced for me, and I have yet to hunt for precise references of those statements. Similarly I thik section 2 of Lurie's *Derived algebraic geometry VII* should do the trick in general. The main problem I have with that reference is that I don't understand if  it does correctly specialize to my case.

Comment: HA 4.1.7.6 is about symmetric monoidal model categories, not necessarily simplicial. 4.1.7.10 *is* about simplicial ones, but it's a different, somewhat more precise statement in that situation

Comment: (It's essentially the same situation as just the underlying $\infty$-category: you have a "plain" statement, where you just look at $A[W^{-1}]$ (or $A^c[W^{-1}]$), and you have a simplicial statement where you look at the homotopy coherent nerve. In fact, when you have a simplicial structure, they agree - this is somewhere in HA or HTT -, but you don't need the simplicial structure to define things)

Comment: In addition, the appendix to "On topological cyclic homology", in particular Theorem A.7 has the statement you want as well.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can't look directly at the model structure on $Ch(QCoh(X))$.  I think you have to do something like define it on $D(Ch(Mod_{O_X}))$ and define $D_{qc}(X)$ to be the triangulated subcategory spanned by those objects whose homology is quasicoherent.    Also, you can always define the injective model structure, but this one is not monoidal.  Hovey had a solution in some special cases, but you need strong finiteness hypotheses:  https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9909024

Comment: @HarryGindi I had not noticed this subtlety, but it actually doesn't matter by a result of Bökstedt-Neeman (*Homotopy limits in triangulated categories*, corollary 5.5) : for a quasicompact semiseparated scheme both constructions coincide.